# jquery date format issue convert datetime column to string with coldfusion

Tags: jquery, mysql, datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a page where first 10 news are displayed serverside (coldfusion), while next set of 10 is loaded on click (ajax, jquery). now, while everything works like a charm serverside, on client i am having issue formatting and displaying date. More specifically, there is one method that loads data (returns query result) and helper component that formats date (sort of) to be shown like this (a few moments ago, 5 hours ago etc). In CF i call function that handles formatting straight from cfoutput. this works flawlessly hence there is no need to post the entire code that mathematically counts range.

```
<cfset loadNews = sql.Getnews(orderBy="Date",startFrom=0)>
<cfset helper = createObject ("component","cfc.helper")>

<cfoutput query="loadNews">
#helper.formatDate(nDate=Date)#
</cfoutput>
```

on the other hand, json returns date like this **September, 29 2013 15:05:45** and in some cases, when local language is changed I can not format date properly and do the same math with javascript(jquery). what's the best, most functional way to get the same functionality on client? should I use query of queries perhaps to convert datetime to string value using the same function and return the result or somehow do everything on client. I would really appreciate your help on this one :(

and yes date in mysql table (datetime column) looks like this 2013-09-30 17:24:56

Comment: Have you tried formatting the date with the DateFormat Function?

Comment: that's the problem function that loads data returns query! so all i can think of is to somehow put it in the loop and format date with DateFormat function as you suggested or use query of queries in order to return string.

Comment: If you have a coldfusion query, you can add a column to it.  Then you can loop through it and assign the string values to that column.

Comment: thanks Dan, i was able to sort it out :) please check out the code below and let me know what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution

```
<cfset newColumn = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop query="qNews">
<cfset arrayAppend(newColumn, helper.formatDate(nDate=qNews.Date))>
</cfloop>
<cfset queryAddColumn(qNews, "fDate", newColumn)>
```